# How do I get rid of the phantom spacing on my HTML page?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why the last line of this grid of photos gets messed up. It is meant to be a nice, clean 3x3 grid of photos.

I think, maybe, the third picture on the second row is causing a problem. If I replace it with another picture it seems to work sometimes, and sometimes the problem persists even with new pictures.

This seems like such basic code, I have no idea what could be causing the problem.

[image: Messed up grid]

```css
h1 {
    font-family: "Raleway";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 23px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
    float: left;
}

.third {
    margin: 1.66%;
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Photo Blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PhotoGalleryStyle.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1 class="third">Photo Gallery</h1>

        <img class="third" src="https://www.thephotoargus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nightsky09.jpg">
        <img class="third" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/1Ys1BTP9bINB_yCEwFpfQuLL2Lq90KoTvTFXGLSno6pxd2p8B54-WA8zUsCIFJZyTyHq6aOHMFKA35QQvpd85pHMy2Nde_UV0t5P_WFLAsd7vixFVwiWe3JiW4-QmB_gdyfvItf9r6rl6yGRg8ngYJYHWhhVRScJSA">
        <img class="third" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/9c/ac/159cac6cc6623a502aebb493f00506a9.jpg">

        <img class="third" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480714378408-67cf0d13bc1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
        <img class="third" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532455935509-eb76842cee50?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80">
        <img class="third" src="https://cdn.anadventurousworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/where-to-stay-in-prague.jpg">

        <img class="third" src="https://www.clickinmoms.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-ways-to-make-your-photos-more-interesting-by-Jamie-Rubeis-11.jpg">
        <img class="third" src="https://loeildelaphotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/FG1_WINOGRAND_New-York-ca-1968.jpg">
        <img class="third" src="https://cdn.emptykingdom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/zona_nunomoreira_2-1.jpg">

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are all your images exactly the same size (I see they get a width of 1000, but what about their height)? This can make one image taller by a single pixel, causing this kind of issue. You might want to use a flexbox layout instead with wrapping enabled.

Comment: Because of the different height of images.

Comment: The image directly above your image that's in the wrong spot, is shorter by .067 px. using floats, the lone image doesn't clear it because technically there is space below that image.

Comment: You can add `img:nth-of-type(3n + 1 ) { clear: left }` and it will fix it. Or you can make sure the images are exactly the same height. Or you can use `flexbox` instead of floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the heights are slightly different you can clear every third element with:

```
img:nth-of-type(3n+1){
  clear:left;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Raleway";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 23px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
  float: left;
}

.third {
  margin: 1.66%;
  width: 30%;
}

img:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Photo Blog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PhotoGalleryStyle.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="third">Photo Gallery</h1>

  <img class="third" src="https://www.thephotoargus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nightsky09.jpg">
  <img class="third" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/1Ys1BTP9bINB_yCEwFpfQuLL2Lq90KoTvTFXGLSno6pxd2p8B54-WA8zUsCIFJZyTyHq6aOHMFKA35QQvpd85pHMy2Nde_UV0t5P_WFLAsd7vixFVwiWe3JiW4-QmB_gdyfvItf9r6rl6yGRg8ngYJYHWhhVRScJSA">
  <img class="third" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/9c/ac/159cac6cc6623a502aebb493f00506a9.jpg">

  <img class="third" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480714378408-67cf0d13bc1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
  <img class="third" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532455935509-eb76842cee50?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80">
  <img class="third" src="https://cdn.anadventurousworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/where-to-stay-in-prague.jpg">

  <img class="third" src="https://www.clickinmoms.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/5-ways-to-make-your-photos-more-interesting-by-Jamie-Rubeis-11.jpg">
  <img class="third" src="https://loeildelaphotographie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/FG1_WINOGRAND_New-York-ca-1968.jpg">
  <img class="third" src="https://cdn.emptykingdom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/zona_nunomoreira_2-1.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This solution works but floating elements is not the way this layout should be achieved. OP should be looking at GRID layout or Flexbox variations to achieve the same outcome without this sort of overhead `:-)`

Comment: @Martin Since this is essentially a one line solution to problem within the context of the markup, is it really more overhead? I say that even given that I commented on the original question about using `flex` as a solution (including the same answer as this)

Comment: Thanks y'all! Flex would be a better way to go. The purpose of this particular page was to practice float, however, which is why we did it this way. Thank you both so much!